# Network folder in finder sidebar disappears

Tags: macos, network, finder, afp

I have added a couple of network folders to the OS X finder sidebar as a shortcut. This is working great as long as I don't shutdown or restart the system. Once the system has been restarted they are no longer visible in finder sidebar. I have also added a Automator script that auto mounts my afp network drive on startup.

Why do network folders disappear? What can do?

Comment: Is it an alias, or the network volume itself? If its a network volume. It will disappear when it disconnects. An alias is just a link to the share. That should not disappear.

Comment: It's a folder from a network volume which I dragged to the OS X sidebar.

Comment: Drag the folder from the share to your desktop (Hold CMD and Alt). Then add that alias to the sidebar

Comment: Fantastic! It's working as described. I have restarted 5x times and the the folder remains in the OS X Sidebar. If you could post that as answer, I will handover the bounty to you.

Comment: For reference: This also happens with external drives which are unmounted at a given time, causing all entries from that drive to disappear from the sidebar. The alias solution bellow worked for me (see my comment).

Comment: The problems and solutions here also apply to Google Drive File Stream!

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Drag the folder from the share to your desktop (Hold CMD and Alt). Then add that alias to the sidebar

Comment: This did not work for me (macOS Sierra) - couldn't drop the alias into the sidebar. What worked was creating a symbolic link via ``ln -s /Volumes/Name ~/Desktop`` and dragging this into the finder sidebar.

Comment: How to add an alias to the sidebar (dragging doesn't work): Go to Finder and highlight the alas, then go to File > "Add to Sidebar".

Comment: ""Add to Sidebar" is greyed out for me if I have an alias selected.

Comment: There is the "Make Alias" option in the context menu (right click) of any folder. You can then move the alias to a convenient location and drag it to the sidebar. I am using macOS 10.14 Mojave.

Comment: I highly recommend creating a symbolic link (`ln -s`), as @psteinweber mentioned, rather than [a macOS alias](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Alias_(Mac_OS)). This allows you to access your network shares via a terminal from the same paths as Finder.

Answer (score 1):

I kept losing folders on an SMB share that I'd dragged to the Finder Favorites. They would stay for a day or two, then vanish. None of the solutions I found online seemed to help (reboot,

I found a way to make them stay there: Make an alias (with contextual menu) to the folder on the SMB share you want a link to. Drag the alias to your desktop. Drag the symbolic link to Finder Favorites. [Mac OS Sierra (10.12.3), MacPro6,1]

Comment: Why resurrect a question with an accepted answer just to post the same answer again?

Comment: Symlinks and aliases are different things. Currently (macOS 10.12.5) aliases cannot be used in Finder sidebar but symlinks can.

Comment: Except that this answer does not actually mention anything about creating a symbolic link (though a comment on the accepted answer does), this was actually the correct answer for macOS Sierra.  Aliases cannot be added to the sidebar, but the symlink can.  Thanks for this!

Answer (score -1):

I was also having an issue dragging aliases into the sidebar. I opened one of the aliases from the desktop, though, and then it would allow me to drop into favorites for some reason.