# Network drive in finder sidebar disappears, is there's a way keep them in unmounted state?

Tags: finder, hard-drive, smb, nas, symlink

I use Automator to mount my network drives on boot by following instructions from this link:

- http://osxdaily.com/2012/05/04/automatically-connect-to-network-drive-mac-os-x/

and then drag the drives on the sidebars favorites panels in Finder. But, the problem arises when the NAS goes to sleep or standby. Finder automatically removes them from there. Then, I followed this:

- [Network folder in finder sidebar disappears](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/245153/network-folder-in-finder-sidebar-disappears)

to create a symlink. Symlink works perfectly in macOS Mojave, until the server goes to sleep  again. Because, the volumes gets unmounted and symlink is broken. But, putting a direct drive link on the sidebar does wakeup the server and remount the drive.

So, is there a way to keep the drive shortcut permanently fixed in the sidebar in their unmounted state? Or a symlink of a shell script file that will mount a drive whenever it is clicked?